# Numpy: np.delete is not removing values in the array

Tags: numpy, debugging, python-3.5

I am using Python `3.5` with numpy version `1.11.3` and I am facing a really weird issue that might be difficult to reproduce.

I loaded a Numpy array `arr1` from a `pd.DataFrame` and `np.delete` does not seem to work:

```
ipdb> np.delete(arr1, 53)
array([  53,   84,  140,  220,  295,  413,  478,  558,  596,  875,  986,
       1103, 1487, 1559, 1704, 1924, 2009, 2044, 2301, 2410, 2514, 2746,
       3432, 3443, 3466, 4054, 4125, 4249, 4309, 4395, 4429, 4544, 4764,
       4787, 5208, 5299, 5340, 5447, 5680, 5899, 5977, 6254, 6256, 6276,
       6412, 6518, 6538, 6584, 6587, 6591, 6592, 6593, 6594, 6661, 6662,
       6663, 6664, 6665, 6666, 6667, 6668, 6669, 6670, 6671, 6672, 6673,
       6686, 6698, 6699, 6700, 6770, 6796, 6848, 6881, 6917, 6975, 7079,
       7121, 7188, 7402, 7510, 8200, 8217, 8479, 8569, 8759, 8925, 9152,
       9190, 9243, 9423, 9485, 9583, 9681, 9690, 9692, 9710, 9793, 9811])

ipdb> arr1.dtype
dtype('int64')

ipdb> np.delete(arr1, arr1)
array([  53,   84,  140,  220,  295,  413,  478,  558,  596,  875,  986,
       1103, 1487, 1559, 1704, 1924, 2009, 2044, 2301, 2410, 2514, 2746,
       3432, 3443, 3466, 4054, 4125, 4249, 4309, 4395, 4429, 4544, 4764,
       4787, 5208, 5299, 5340, 5447, 5680, 5899, 5977, 6254, 6256, 6276,
       6412, 6518, 6538, 6584, 6587, 6591, 6592, 6593, 6594, 6661, 6662,
       6663, 6664, 6665, 6666, 6667, 6668, 6669, 6670, 6671, 6672, 6673,
       6686, 6698, 6699, 6700, 6770, 6796, 6848, 6881, 6917, 6975, 7079,
       7121, 7188, 7402, 7510, 8200, 8217, 8479, 8569, 8759, 8925, 9152,
       9190, 9243, 9423, 9485, 9583, 9681, 9690, 9692, 9710, 9793, 9811])
```

However it works when I call `np.delete` on `np.arange`:

```
ipdb> np.delete(np.arange(15), np.arange(13))
array([13, 14])
```

Is there an explanation why this might happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of [`numpy.delete`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) is not the *value* to be deleted.  It is the index (or indices) to be deleted.  Take a look at the examples in the docstring, such as this one:

```
In [25]: arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])

In [26]: arr
Out[26]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])

In [27]: np.delete(arr, 1, axis=0)
Out[27]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

The value `1` in that function call, combined with `axis=0`, means "delete the row with index 1".